# How to unsubscribe from mail by usng JAVA ,Rest API?

Tags: java, mysql, rest, smtp

I am doing a poc and basic learner. I am sending mail to user while subscribe(channel) from my application. User is receiving a mail. Now I wanted to implement Unsubscribe it.
So I planned to send unsubscribe link to mail. But user clicking on the unsubscribe, What should i do? How to implement the service api? Should i need Security? Can you please help me to approach the way to implement unsubscribe user from the channel?

I am using the following technologies: SMTP, JAVA, Rest, database mysql, Angular.

Comment: Hi, your question is quite broad. I'm not sure how much help we can be here. In every email you send to your users, send a unique "unsubscribe" link. Then when they click it, remove the user from the mailing list. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Thanks. But do we need service api for unsubscribe? what are the technologies can be used?Do we need SSO or any Security token needed for this to identify the user?

Comment: You'll probably need an "unsubscribe" REST endpoint. You should use some sort of non-guessable UUID to identify each user (so people don't unsubscribe other people). You can store a map of "unsubscribe tokens" to "user ids" on the backend to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got good idea. If any example program for this, kindly share it.